# What penetrates deeper in water? Blue or voilet?

Tags: visible-light

I was wondering about what colour of light penetrates deepest, and stumbled upon this pic while reading about related content.

[image: Light penetration in water]

The pic shows, violet is penetrated to a lesser extent than blue.

If this information is right, what could be the possible explanation?

If light with higher energy penetrates deeper, then violet should reach to greatest of depth. Or is it because water absorbs violet light?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Wikipedia article on light absorption by water](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electromagnetic_absorption_by_water#Visible_region) includes this graph of absorption in the visible region:

[image: Absorption by water]

The minimum absorption, and therefore the greatest penetration is around $\lambda = 420$nm, which is on the boundary between blue and violet light.

However the spectrum of sunlight looks like this:

[image: Sunlight]

([picture from here](https://www.e-education.psu.edu/earth103/node/1006))

Note that the intensity of sunlight peaks between $\lambda = 500$ and $550$nm and it falls rapidly at smaller wavelengths. So even though water absorbs least at violet wavelengths the light intensity decreases because there isn't that much violet light in sunlight.

The maximum penetration at around $\lambda = 475$nm is a trade off between the decreased absorption and decreased intensity as the wavelength decreases.

Comment: To speak of a sunlight-spectrum-corrected maximum penetration without regard for the distance of water to penetrate is rather arbitrary.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP: presumably the article that the original figure came from is taking some arbitrary cut-off intensity and solving $I(\lambda)=I_0(\lambda)exp(-a_\lambda d)$ to get the depths shown in the figure.

Comment: Oh, I see. The first time I loaded the page, that figure didn't show up. My bad.

Comment: On second thoughts, isn't that figure dealing with sunlight which actually penetrates the atmosphere, but has nothing to do with penetrating water?

Comment: @John Rennie Thanks for such a  beautiful explanation. So, the extent to which different wavelength of light is absorbed by water (or any media) is independent of energy possessed by the light?

Comment: @Tushar I'm quite convinced, that's not what John tried to say. In fact, the first figure shows the wavelength dependence of absorption of light by water (as you can see, it's certainly wavelength-dependent), wavelength is in turn inversely proportional to frequency that is proportional to energy. Or did you mean to say, that absorption is independent of the intensity of light at a given wavelength? That is mostly true, though at very high intensities you may start to notice non-linear effects.

Comment: @LLlAMnYP That makes it clear. And I did not meant "absorption is independent of the intensity of light at a given wavelength".

So to sum it up: General trend of penetration is: Higher the energy of a light wave, greater will be the penetration. BUT violet penetrates lesser than blue because the sunlight on our planet have lesser violet than blue.

Comment: @Tushar nope, can't agree with your last sentence. Look closely at the first figure, you can see the absorption starting to go up for the shortest wavelengths. So yeah, blue-violet may penetrate better than red, orange, etc. but deep-violet and ultraviolet penetrate not so much. And this has nothing to do with the exact composition of sunlight, this is a property of water itself.

Comment: @JohnRennie -- You picked one of two conflicting graphs from the same wikipedia page. The other graph shows a minimum at just under 500 nm, a greenish blue. Yet another conflicting wikipedia page is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_properties_of_water_and_ice, which has a table in increments of 25 nm that shows a minimum $k$ value at 475 nm, or smack dab in the middle of blue.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the conflicting wiki graphs (mentioned in the last comment) originate from the exact definitions of absorption (e.g. if scattering is taken into account, what type of light source etc.) as well as whether you use a theoritical model or empirical data.
This page https://omlc.org/spectra/water/abs/index.html suggests that the minimum is now around 420ish nm, close to Rennie's answer. The convolution of that absorption curve with the solar spectrum (which also depends on time, location, conditions etc.) at sea level, combined with the various water conditions can be turned into a practical answer (for divers, submariners etc.) of roughly 475nm. Probably plus or minus 20nm depending on the conditions I mentioned.